# Using edit-form while it´s loading

Tags: 8

In my installation (Drupal 8 with paragraphs) firing multiple ajaxcalls by clicking the "edit"-button on paragraphs or "add paragraph"-buttons **before the loading symbol from a previous click disappeared** can lead to unexpected behaviour.

This behaviour includes nested paragraphs being unpublished or the disappearance of all paragraphs. The behaviour is not consistant. These faulty forms can sometimes still be saved, i.e. a paragraph and all it´s children are suddenly unpublished.

**This could be solved by making the buttons unclickable while anything is loading.** However, imho this is not a desirable solution since it only circumvents the problem and doesn´t provide a clean workflow anymore and can probably lead to other errors.

Has anybody else encountered this problem or has a good idea on how to solve this?

Comment: There is an open issue about this [Multiple AJAX actions at once breaks paragraphs fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2829716)

Comment: `can probably lead to other errors` I don't think so if solved via custom JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: The first comment actually lead me to this: [Concurrent ajax submits cause user data loss](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2830295)
So this seems to be a core issue and not particularly related to paragraphs. The fix introduced in the patch is the kind of solution I was hoping for. Thanks a lot @NoSssweat! 
There is also some discussion about disabling the buttons (#21,#24). 

Custom JS that depends on Core JS can break on updates or edge cases I´m not thinking of right now; I guess what I wanted to say is that I do not want the additional JS-maintenance.